# Using WhenEvent with DSolve (not NDSolve)

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

The documentation says

> WhenEvent expressions can be used in NDSolve, NDSolveValue, ParametricNDSolve, ParametricNDSolveValue, **DSolve**, and DSolveValue.

But when I try this toy case

```
DSolve[{f[0]==0,f'[t]==2,WhenEvent[f[t]==5,f[t]->10]},f,t]
```

It complains that

> Equation or list of equations expected instead of WhenEvent[f[t]==5,f[t]->10] in the first argument {f[0]==0,f'[t]==2,WhenEvent[f[t]==5,f[t]->10]}

But when I use this same `eqn` in `NDSolve` it works fine. So how do I get `WhenEvent` working with `DSolve`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation of [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html), this is classified as a hybrid-differential equation.

You need to specify the range of `t` something like `{0, 10}`

```
DSolve[{f[0] == 0, f'[t] == 2, WhenEvent[f[t] == 5, f[t] -> 10]}, f[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

> [image]

Comment: Well now when I look at the DSolve page that's obvious, I swear I checked that already... Thanks. They really should have a better error for that though.