# If condition in differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, conditional, event-detection

I need to plot the Integrate the Fire model of neuron. The differential equation is $\frac{dV}{dt} + \frac{V}{\tau} = \frac{I}{C}$. The initial condition is $V(0) = 0$. And there is this condition if whenever $V(t) = \theta$ then $V(t+h) = 0$ where h->0. If you leave the condition then I know how to solve the equation using `NDSolve` but I don't know how to use that condition and sove the equation.
Sample Values $I = 60 × 10^{-9}, R = 10^9,C = 10^{-11}, \theta=5$.

Edit1 - Code for NDSolve using WhenEvent[]  `NDSolve[{V'[t]+ V[t]/0.01 == 6000,V[0]==0,WhenEvent[V[t]==50,V[t]->0]},V[t],{t,0,10}]`.

Code for `DSolve`  using WhenEvent-> `DSolve[{V'[t]+ V[t]/0.01 == 6000,V[0]==0,WhenEvent[V[t]==50,V[t]->0]},V[t],{t,0,0.1}]`. Here you need to specify the range also.

Thanks everyone who helped.

Comment: Look up `WhenEvent[]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, it worked for the ```NDSolve```. I want to ask can something similar to ```WhenEvent``` be done for ```DSolve``` also.

Comment: `it worked for the NDSolve` Why then not post the code you used? This will make it easier to use it as starting point. `WhenEvent` is supposed to work for `DSolve` also. There is example here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165405/using-whenevent-with-dsolve-not-ndsolve

Comment: @Nasser Actually, you need to specify the range for independent variable in the DSolve when using with WhenEvent. I missed the range, as I had never put range in ```DSolve``` till now. Thanks for the help.